# overwriting the existing sheet in excel

Tags: excel, overwrite

it add sheet in excel but after the code is done running the excel file will only have 1 sheet. note that i have sheet a sheet name template inside the excel.

```
def createNewSheet(currentDate):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('employee_data.xlsx')
    sheetNames = wb.sheetnames

    # Check if the current_date sheet already exists
    sheetExists = False
    for sheetName in sheetNames:
        if sheetName == currentDate:
            sheetExists = True
            break

    if not sheetExists:
        # Create a new sheet
        newSheet = wb.create_sheet(title=currentDate)

        # Read data from the 'Template' sheet using pandas
        df_template = pd.read_excel('employee_data.xlsx', sheet_name='Template', engine='openpyxl')

        # Get the column headers from the 'Template' sheet
        headers = df_template.columns.tolist()

        # Write the column headers to the new sheet
        for col_num, header in enumerate(headers, start=1):
            newSheet.cell(row=1, column=col_num, value=header)

        # Copy data starting from row 2 (A2 to last row) to the new sheet
        for row_num, row in enumerate(df_template.values, start=2):
            for col_num, value in enumerate(row, start=1):
                newSheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num, value=value)

        # Save the new sheet to the workbook
        wb.save('employee_data.xlsx')


currentDate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
createNewSheet(currentDate)
```

i want it to add sheet and name it with the current date after that it will copy the data from the "Template" sheet.

Comment: Pls add additional tags to correspond language python? openpyxl?